# How to compute modulo of md5 in R?

Tags: r, md5, modulo

The title says it all...

I know that I can use `digest::digest` to compute the `md5` of a string:

```
digest::digest('string', algo = "md5", serialize = FALSE)
```

However, I'm at a loss for how I can convert this (presumably hexadecimal) value into an integer (or big int) for modulo purposes...

My attempts to use `as.hexmode` and `strtoi` have both failed.

```
> as.hexmode(digest("1", algo = "md5", serialize = FALSE))
Error in as.hexmode(digest("1", algo = "md5", serialize = FALSE)) :
'x' cannot be coerced to class "hexmode"

> strtoi(digest("1", algo = "md5", serialize = FALSE), base = 16L)
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the resulting number is too high to be represented as an integer, and `strtoi` returns NA. Since you need only the lower numbers for the modulo, why not just convert the end of the md5-string? This example does not give the same result as the next (correct) solution with Rmpfr.

```
x <- digest::digest('string', algo = "md5", serialize = FALSE)
strtoi(substr(x, nchar(x)-4, nchar(x)), base=16)
```

---

Another solution is to use the Rmpfr library, which supports conversion of large integers. This gives the correct conversion result (but requires an additional package):

```
library(Rmpfr)
x <- digest::digest('string', algo = "md5", serialize = FALSE)
x <- mpfr(x, base=16)
x %% 1000
```

Comment: Both of these snippets give integers, however they do not return the same results (absolutely, as well as modulo 100). The results of the first snippet are (obviously) sensitive to the size of the substring...

Comment: This is indeed correct. I updated the answer to be more clear about this issue.